# How do I curl a page that needs first clicking a consent button?

Tags: curl, web-scraping, cookies, puppeteer, wget

I like to curl a URL like [this](https://techcrunch.com/2020/10/12/free-to-play-gaming-giant-roblox-confidentially-files-to-go-public/). (The URL requires consent in EU countries when you have no cookies for the site.)

I cobbled up a puppeteer script that does this, but it looks quite heavyweight and  brittle to me. Any better solutions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const url = process.argv[2];
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()


  await page.goto(url)

  await page.waitForSelector('.con-wizard > .wizard-body > #consent-text > .content-list > .list-item:nth-child(1)')
  await page.click('.con-wizard > .wizard-body > #consent-text > .content-list > .list-item:nth-child(1)')

  await page.waitForSelector('.con-wizard > .wizard-body > .actions > .consent-form > .primary')
  await page.click('.con-wizard > .wizard-body > .actions > .consent-form > .primary')


    const timeout = ((process.env.cfTimeout) || 20) * 1000

    await page.waitFor(timeout);
    const html = await page.content();
    console.log(html);

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in doing this with plain curl, by monitoring the requests in Chrome's network pane:

```
function techcrunch-curl() {
    local url="${1:?}"
    local con="$(curl -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $url)"
    if [[ "$con" =~ 'https://consent\.yahoo\.com/v2/collectConsent\?sessionId=(.*)' ]] ; then
        local sid="${match[1]}"

        curl -o /dev/stdout --fail --location --cookie-jar =() 'https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId='$sid \
            -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
            -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
            -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
            -H 'Origin: https://consent.yahoo.com' \
            -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
            -H 'DNT: 1' \
            -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
            -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36' \
            -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
            -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
            -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
            -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
            -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
            -H 'Referer: https://consent.yahoo.com/v2/collectConsent?sessionId='$sid \
            -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
            --data-raw 'sessionId='$sid'&originalDoneUrl='"$(<<<$url url-encode.py)"'&namespace=techcrunch&agree=agree&agree=agree' \
            --compressed
    else
        curl $url
    fi
}
```